# How to configure the base url of a Catalyst application?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have developed a Catalyst application, which runs via the catalyst development server at, say, `localhost:3000`. Next I configured Apache to proxy requests to `http://myhost/myapp/` to `localhost:3000` using mod_proxy.

I would now like Catalyst to know that it has been publicly relocated to the base url `myapp/` and take it into account when forming URLs via `uri_for`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have a reason for using a proxy in this manner?  Why not just use Apache to run the Catalyst app?

Comment: It is a shared hosting and installing mod_fcgi seems like more of a hassle than proxying. In any case, setting up application root should be a matter of a single config option, right?

Comment: Probably it's not even correct or could be seen as a hackery, but try to alter your base URL in Root::auto like this `$c->req->base($c->req->base . 'myapp/')`. This assumes you use it as simple as you described and a static string is enough.

Comment: the working hackery is `$c->req->base(URI->new($c->req->base . 'myapp/'))`, the previous one just sets an unblessed string and creates problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KT, the easiest thing to do is to install `Catalyst::TraitFor::Request::ProxyBase`, as it is specifically designed to replace request base with the value passed by HTTP proxy.

The module is completely transparent and requires no modification of the existing app.